# debootstrap not retrieving release

Tags: ubuntu

im trying to install a image on an cf card, last time it worked just fine. but now i only get "Retrieving Release", my shellcommand:
"sudo debootstrap --arch i386 lucid /mnt/mstr  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
Answer is: "I: Retrieving Release" and then its stuck.

Im behind an proxy but the apt-get stuff is working fine.

now i added in the bash.bashrc:
export http_proxy=http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/

in my apt.conf it was still there:
Acquire::http::proxy "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/";

With UMTS-Router its working fine, so its the Proxy i guess, any ideas to fix?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I'll answer anyway, as I've just seen the same issue. The problem is a bug in cdebootstrap 0.55, as shipped with ubuntu lucid. See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=587526

My solution was to grab the source package for 0.57 from natty and requild for lucid. It then worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but might help somebody with the same problem.
In sudo there's usually a line

Defaults env_reset

the proxy settings will not be copied to the new root environment.

To check, type the following :

sudo env |grep http_proxy

If you don't see any output then sudo is cleaning your environment.
Use visudo and add a line :

Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy no_proxy"

Answer (score 0):

The request to retrieve the release file is hanging.  That indicates a network problem; `tcpdump` should show you exactly where it's happening.

How are you configuring the proxy for apt-get?  If you don't have `http_proxy` set in the environment (that's case-sensitive, by the way) then that would cause the problems you're seeing.

**EDIT**

Based on the `tcpdump` output you posted, `debootstrap` is attempting to contact the Ubuntu servers directly; this means that it's *not* using your local proxy, which brings me back to the `http_proxy` environment variable not being set.

Comment: Over the gui, but i also checked the apt.conf and its there also. the tcpdump doenst help me either. its printing something like this:  10:26:08.444677 IP UbMark.49128 > drescher.canonical.com.www: Flags [S], seq 1031662602, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 15940000 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
if i make tcpdump host archive.ubuntu.com !

Comment: Add pertinent information to your question, where it can be properly formatted, rather than in a comment where it's nigh unreadable.

Comment: I updated the first post, its still not working :(

Comment: Did you log out and back in again after modifying `bashrc`?  Verify that it's set correctly by running `echo $http_proxy` to make sure it's actually set, and `wget -O - http://google.com/` to make sure *something* can get out via the proxy.

Comment: Echo is printing the ip of the proxy and wget downloaded index.html, but still only Retrieving Release!

Comment: Time for more `tcpdump` and `strace`; adding the `--verbose` option to `debootstrap` might be worth a shot too, to see how wget's going behind the scenes.  Also, `http_proxy` must be a URL, not a bare IP address (your question suggests you know that, but mention of "ip of the proxy" in your comment makes me nervous).

Comment: Answer of the echo http_proxy is: http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/. I added the output of the strace in the first post, what should i tcpdump?

Comment: Add pertinent information to your question, where it can be properly formatted, rather than in a comment where it's nigh unreadable.

Comment: Done, tell me what you need to be tcdumped

Comment: From op: Output of strace: http://pastie.org/2354893
$http_proxy == http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/

Comment: So, i testet it with the umts router and its working fine, so its the proxy i guess. Any ideas to fix?

Comment: `strace`ing a shell script without -f isn't too helpful (`bash -x` is more useful, but still not diagnostically relevant in this case), and **this sort of information belongs in the question, not a comment** (I can't believe I'm having to say this three times, including once to a mod)

Comment: Iam editing the startpost all the time? and the mod  edited my startpost and postet the stuff in comments...so dont know what you mean. If you see, its working with the umts router so the proxy is the problem i guess.Iam entered it into the bash.bashrc, etc/profile/ apt.conf files but nothing.

Comment: According to the public edit history, there are two edits to the question, both done by you, neither of which contain any output from `strace`.

Comment: Mark Henderson took my pastie.org link from the startpost, posted it as an comment and erased it in the startpost and i wrote that i added the output in the first post if you see!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not the exact same issue, but I had a similar problem just now, apt-get working fine, just keep hanging while retrieving the release.

I decided to change the repository on /etc/apt/sources.list just for the heck of it and it worked... again, apt-get update / install was working fine, go figure.